# Do references in the research papers' state of the art section need to be referred in chronological order?

Tags: publications, citations

Do references in the research papers' state of the art section need to be referred in chronological order?
In other words, is it important that the state of the art section mentions the papers of previous research in the same order they were published?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have an advisor you.can ask?

Comment: Have you bothered to *read* a few original papers (perhaps ones you might reference?) and looked how they've structured their references?

Answer (score 14):

Typically, "the state of the art" is not monolithic. Rather, it consists of multiple strands or aspects. If your paper addresses the application of technique *foo* to problem *bar*, then "the state of the art" will need to look at the development of technique *foo*, as well as current knowledge and previous work on problem *bar*.

You should first of all separate your literature review into these aspects: don't mix references on *foo* with those on *bar*. Rather, explain the current state of the art for *foo* first, then for *bar* (or the other way around). If someone has already applied *foo* to *bar*, then that would be a third major section.

Within these sections, there may be logical subdivisions, like different major approaches to *bar*, or different flavors of *foo*. It makes sense to put each such subdivision into a separate paragraph or so.

Once you have found a useful level or granularity of analysis, work in a *logical* order, not necessarily a *chronological* one. Given that much of research consists of building on previous work, usually the logical order is also chronological, but it need not be. Readers are usually more interested in the logical structure, less in who published what first.

Comment: You're missing a "d" at the and of the first sentence of the second paragraph. Right before the dot.

Comment: @DonQuiKong "bard"? Are you familiar with [*Foo* and *bar*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) as placeholders?

Comment: @ChrisH bard is also good, but it said something about the flavour of foo(d) there previously.

Comment: @DonQuiKong that's the third paragraph.  "Flavours" of *foo* (or any other placeholder) works as meaning varieties, though it's a little surprising for "flavour" to describe something that's almost but not quite "food" after all

Comment: Just to clarify, I *did* mean "foo" and "bar" in the sense that @ChrisH linked to on Wikipedia, and I was a little lost at where exactly a d was missing... I'll remember not to discuss "flavors of foo" any more in the future!

Comment: @StephanKolassa surely you were just checking we're paying attention?

Comment: @ChrisH: indeed you overestimate my deviousness.

Comment: @chrish oh, maybe I miscounted the paragraphs. And for the record - I know what foo and bar are, thought I'd be funny. But I'd better learn counting before.

Answer (score 1):

I would say chronological order only for the first couple of citations where you are introducing the problem and field. In the sense that you should be citing the first work(s) on the topic, first, when introducing things. But after that cite in the order that makes sense for the text your writing.

Comment: "Cite in the order that makes sense for the text you're writing." Always.